# Экспорт в excel из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Неправильно выводит данные на excell. Мне надо чтобы каждый атрибут на каждой колонке выходил. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: Вывод на excell]

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $name);
            $comma = ",";
        }

        $seperator .= "\n";

        fputs($fp, $seperator);
        mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {

        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

            foreach ($row as $name => $value) {

                $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $value);
                $comma = ",";
            }
        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp, $seperator);
        }

        fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Это как я понимаю не XLS, а CSV . Надо сделать его как CSV и когда Excel спросит  при открытии что считать разделителями, указать запятую, если хочется действительно родной XLS, то нужна библиотека, потому что у него не такой простой формат, ну да просто попробуйте создать табличку и открыть её в Notepad